# strict aliasing и char*

Tags: c++, c, strict-aliasing

Пытаюсь понять, в какой мере `strict aliasing rule` не касается `char`.

Во многих источниках делается акцент на том, что `char` может накладываться на любой тип, но не наоборот. Что это значит?

Допустим:

```
int i;

int *pi = &i;
char *pc = (char*)&i;

// Первый случай.
*pc = 0;
*pi = 1;
// *pc != 0?

// Второй случай.
*pi = 0;
*pc = 1;
// *pi != 0?
```

Исключим из рассмотрения порядок байтов, требования выравнивания и прочие штуки.

Верно ли я понимаю, что в связи с однонаправленностью описанного правила, один из описанных случаев будет корректен, а другой - вызовет неопределенное поведение?

Или же правило описывает иную ситуацию, и оба приведенных случая не выльются в неопределенное поведение?

Идентично ли поведение `C` и `C++`?

Я совершенно запутался с этим `sa`...

Comment: На практике, код, который будет сгенерен (со strict aliasing) зависит не столько от стандартов языка, сколько от каждого конкретного компилятора, уровня опптимизации и окружающего языкового контекста. Т.е. компилируете с `-S`  и читаете асм.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых что такое "strict aliasing" (в двух словах) - это *следствие* из ограниченности перечня типов выражений, для которых в стандарте определяется поведение при обращение к объекту определенного типа. Это следствие заключается в том, что у компилятора появляется возможность считать, **что указатели (и ссылки) несовместных типов никогда не указывают на одно и то же место в памяти**, то бишь что они не являются алиасами одного и того же объекта.

Более формально этот перечень определен так:

> **8.2 Properties of expressions [expr.prop]**
>   11 If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined: 63
>   (11.1) — the dynamic type of the object,
>   (11.2) — a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
>   (11.3) — a type similar (as defined in 7.5) to the dynamic type of the object,
>   (11.4) — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,
>   (11.5) — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
>   (11.6) — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or non-static data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate or contained union),
>   (11.7) — a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of the dynamic type of the object, 
>   (11.8) — a char, unsigned char, or std::byte type.

Что же особенного в `char`? Дело в том, что модель памяти основана на адресации байт и все объекты в языке имеют байтовое представление. Последний пункт в перечне как раз разрешает получение доступа к байтовому представлению (*object representation*).

Однако заметьте, что эти правила относятся непосредственно к доступу к объекту, то бишь левой части выражения `*pc = 0;`. А само присваивание работает потому что для тривиально-копируемых объектов разрешено копирование байт туда-сюда.

Далее, приведенный в вопросе "второй случай" на самом деле ничем не отличается от первого. Обратный пример тут должен был бы выглядеть вот так:

```
alignas(int) char bytes[sizeof(int)]{};
char * pc{static_cast<char *>(bytes)};
int * pi{reinterpret_cast<int *>(pc)};
*pi = 1; // неопределенное поведение!
```

Но это еще не все, дело в том, что в имеется возможность *размещать* объекты в памяти (*provide storage*)!

```
alignas(int) char bytes[sizeof(int)]{};
char * pc{static_cast<char *>(bytes)};
int * pi1{new(pc) int{}};
*pi1 = 1; // определенное поведение!
int * pi2{reinterpret_cast<int *>(pc)};
*pi2 = 1; // (внезапно) по-прежнему неопределенное поведение, хотя pi2 == pi1!
```

Comment: верно ли мое понимание? Допустим, у нас есть три указателя: `char *c`, `int *i` и `float *f`. Компилятор считает, что изменение данных через `c` может иметь последствия для данных `f` или `i`. Так же он считает, что изменение данных через `f` или `i` может иметь последствия для данных `c`. Однако, в его представлении изменение `f` не влияет на `i` и изменение `i` не влияет на `f`. Все верно?

Comment: @MGNeo Вроде так.