# Безопасно ли получать адрес члена невыровненной структуры

Tags: c++, c, выравнивание

Меня интересует следующий вопрос:

```
struct S
{
    // ...
    int i;
};

void f(uint8_t *_buf, size_t _offset)
{
    uint8_t *pu = _buf + _offset;
    S *ps = (S*)pu;
    int *pi = &(ps->i);// UB or not UB?

    int i;
    memcpy(&i, pi, sizeof(int));
}
```

У нас есть буфер байтов и смещение. По указанному смещению в буфере лежит объект типа `S`. Этот объект имеет неверное выравнивание, как и поле `i` этого объекта.

Меня интересует, можно ли получить адрес поля `i` описанным образом, чтобы потом считать `int` с указанного адреса безопасным способом - по одному байту или при помощи `memcpy()`.

Comment: Кажется, само создание (любым способом) указателя с типом `int *` на невыровненный `int` скорее всего дает UB (по аналогии с https://stackoverflow.com/a/28895321/2752075), но точных ссылок на стандарт у меня нет.

Comment: Что значит "объект имеет неверное выравнивание"?

Comment: Еще, на каком языке вы пишете, С или С++? Или вам нужны ссылки на стандарт на оба языка?

Comment: Пишу на обоих языках.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### C99 6.3.2.3/7

> A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be converted to a pointer to a different object or incomplete type. *If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the pointed-to type, **the behavior is undefined**.* *Otherwise...

**Вольный перевод:**

> Указатель на объект или неполный тип может быть преобразован в указатель на другой объект или неполный тип. *Если результирующий указатель не выровнен корректно для типа, на который он будет указывать, **поведение неопределено**.* Иначе...

Т.е. со строгих слов стандарта Си получение любого не выровненного указателя, не зависимо от того, будет ли по нему доступ к памяти или нет — UB.

Comment: ЕМНИП по этому поводу уже не однократно копья ломали... только вот ссылок я что-то найти ни как не могу...

Comment: Я постоянно вижу такой код. Получается, это однозначное `UB`, и никакого поведения, определяемого реализацией, ожидать не стоит?

Comment: @MGNeo, я сам из лагеря тех, кто считал, что здесь всё в порядке... и мне, честно сказать, сложно представить архитектуру и разумную реализацию под неё, где это могло бы дать неправильный результат (разве что какие-то хитрые агрессивные оптимизации)... но с Писанием не поспоришь...

Comment: А вы дальше читали тот пункт, на который ссылаетесь? *When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object*

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, с `char*` совсем другая история. Он может алиасить что угодно и указывать куда угодно.

Comment: @MGNeo в вашем коде комментарий про UB, кстати, получается надо на стоку выше поднять. А чтобы получить данные - создать временную переменную типа `S` и замемкопить в неё данные из буфера.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, дык в вопросе преобразования __в__ `char` и нет, есть только обратное... не вижу как это к делу относится...

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, вы абсолютно правы.

Answer (score 3):

Для этого будет достаточно взять смещение этого поля от начала структуры без каких-либо промежуточных указателей (подразумевается, что структура является standard layout type):

```
::std::memcpy(::std::addressof(i), _buf + _offset + offsetof(S, i), sizeof(i));
```

Что касается попытки преобразования указателя на объект с менее строгим выравниванием к указателю на объект с более строгим выравниванием, то в С++ поведение не специфицировано (то бишь задается реализацией):

> **8.5.1.10 Reinterpret cast [expr.reinterpret.cast]**
> 7 An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type. 73 When a prvalue `v` of object pointer type is converted to the object pointer type “pointer to cv `T` ”, the result is `static_cast<cv T*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))`. [Note: Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to `T1`” to the type “pointer to `T2`” (where `T1` and `T2` are object types and where the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value. —end note ]
>
> **8.5.1.9 Static cast [expr.static.cast]**
>
> 13 A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 `void`” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 `T`”, where `T` is an object type and cv2 is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1. If the original pointer value represents the address `A` of a byte in memory and `A` does not satisfy the alignment requirement of `T`, then the resulting pointer value is unspecified. Otherwise, if the original pointer value points to an object `a`, and there is an object `b` of type `T` (ignoring cv-qualification) that is pointer-interconvertible (6.7.2) with `a`, the result is a pointer to `b`. Otherwise, the pointer value is unchanged by the conversion.

Но вот использовать полученный указатель на структуру (даже если реализация правильно производит преобразование адреса) для получения указателя на поле этой структуры уже [будет неопределенным поведением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/953152/strict-aliasing-%D0%B8-char/953375#953375).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91303/discussion-on-answer-by-vtt-------).