# Как преобразовать структуру к массиву байт фиксированной длины?

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы, структуры-данных, типы-данных

Продолжаю исследование возможностей и невозможностей C++. Есть у меня заполненная структура, допустим тот же `tube`:

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct tube
{
  BYTE var1;    
  size_t var2;         
  BYTE  var3;    
};
#pragma pack()
```

Допустим, я его заполняю:

```
tube *MyFunc(){
    tube *t = new tube();
    t->var1 = 0;
    t->var2 = 0x04030201;
    t->var3 = 0x05;
    return t;
}
```

Я заведомо знаю размер структуры. Под x86 - это 6 байт. Как я могу преобразовать структуру tube к массиву байт **фиксированной** длины? Т.е., например, к `BYTE rez[6];`.

Пробовал:

```
rez = (BYTE*)MyFunc();
rez = (BYTE[])MyFunc();
rez = (BYTE[6])MyFunc();
rez = static_cast<BYTE[6]>(MyFunc());
```

Но в любом случае получаю какую-либо ошибку.
Понимаю, что могу выделить память через `new`:

```
BYTE rez = new BYTE[6];
rez = (BYTE*)MyFunc();
```

Но ведь это немного не то.

Получается, что статический массив и динамический массив - это принципиально разные типы данных в C++, точно так же, как и фиксированные массивы разной длины. Так ли это?

Comment: Массив является неприсваиваемым. Присваивать можно указатели - объявите `BYTE* rez` и присваивайте на здоровье...

Comment: *Преобразовать* можно так: `reinterpret_cast<BYTE ( & )[6]>(*MyFunc())`, только обращение к массиву через полученную ссылку будет неопределенным поведением. *Копировать* можно так `::std::memcpy(::std::addressof(rez), MyFunc(), sizeof(rez));`. Кроме того, важно различать указатели и массивы, это не одно и то же!

Comment: @VTT, странно, что неопределенное. Во всяком случае, для меня это не очевидно. Ведь мы работаем одинаково с указателем на динамический массив и статическим массивом: для `BYTE rez = new BYTE[6]` и `BYTE rez[6]` обращение `rez[0]=0x05;cout << rez[0];` имеет одинаковое значение или это кажущееся впечатление?

Comment: `BYTE rez = new BYTE[6]` вообще синтаксическая ошибка. А если `rez` - массив, то выражение `rez[0]` будет эквивалентно получению указателя на первый элемент и применению оператора индексирования. А поведению будет неопределенно потому что указатель, возвращаемый из функции, указывает на структуру `tube`, см [strict aliasing и char*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/953152/strict-aliasing-и-char/953375#953375)

Comment: @VTT, забыл звездочку поставить BYTE *rez = new BYTE[6]. Насколько я понял, в ответе по ссылке речь идет о преобразовании типов данных разных размеров? Но если я слежу за размерностью, то неопределенного поведения быть не должно?

Comment: @VTT, секундочку, ЕМНИП, strict aliasing не распространяется на `char*`. Если `#define BYTE unsigned char`, никакого UB нет.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb см [strict aliasing и char*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/953152/strict-aliasing-и-char/953375#953375)

Comment: @VTT, вы хотите чтобы я там этот вопрос продублировал? В с стандарте [написано](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11) чёрными по белому, что можно обращаться к памяти через указатель на то, что там на самом деле лежит и через `char*`. И вот мне интересно откуда вы взяли, что алиасинг с `char*` это ub?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb А с чего вы взяли, что я взял, что алиасинг с char * это UB? В том ответе говорится как раз наоборот. А в моем первом комментарии к этому вопросу алиасинг с char * (или BYTE *) не затрагивается. Заметьте, что там кастование к ссылке на массив, а не к указателю.

Comment: Напишите `BYTE *rez = (BYTE *)MyFunc();` и получите указатель на структуру. `for (int i; i < sizeof(tube); i++) printf("%x ", rez[i]);` выведет hex ее байтов через пробел. / Если вы хотите скопировать результат `MyFunc()` в массив, то напишите: `BYTE rez[sizeof(tube)]; memcpy((char *)rez, (char *)MyFunc(), sizeof(tube));`

Comment: Если же вспомнить о том, что операция присваивания (копирование) применима к структурам, то можно написать и так: `BYTE rez[sizeof(tube)];
  *((tube *)rez) = *MyFunc();`

Comment: @avp, спасибо! Кажется, это то, что я искал)

Comment: @digital-mag,вот и хорошо. Все это есть в книжках, я бы даже сказал, что достаточно одной -- [K&R](https://www.dipmat.univpm.it/~demeio/public/the_c_programming_language_2.pdf) (всего-то 300 страниц). Ну, потом, пожалуй  имеет смысл прочесть [Практику программирования](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1927500/) и для общего развития в области языков [Языки программирования: разработка и реализация](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1158230/)

Comment: @avp, чувствую, мне это трудно для понимания. Наверное, нужно больше практики